# Receive a variable in http header PHP

Tags: php, android, curl, http-headers

I know this question is not going to be so clear as most similar questions on here are talking about sending headers, also there's a lot of questions similar to but not answering this specifically, also sorry if the answer is extremely obvious.

So I've got an apk that sends `X-API-Key` in the header PHP conversion of this code is:

```
$url = 'example.something.org/test.php';
$data = "$some_data";
$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-API-KEY"=>"FIND_MEEEEEEEE"));
```

What I want is to collect the `X-API-KEY` and store it as a variable so that I can then send another request from test.php similar to the one shown, its not an option to run the request directly from the apk as I don't want this data stored client side, I need the `X-API-KEY` for the request being sent from the server, so technically it is like this apk->my_server->external_server

I have tried using `print_r` for `$_POST` and `$_SERVER` echoed all keys in `header()` multiple other things that I can't even think of right now as I've tried everything and searched Google as much as possible.

Please link to answer if this has been answered already.

**EDIT:**
I've also tried using this js code which gives me the exact same headers:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set header as:-

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    "X-API-KEY"=>"FIND_MEEEEEEEE"
);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

in your `test.php` file write this lines:-

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Ive tried the 'foreach loop' on the test.php, im not sure as to why it doesnt show, it works fine when interacting with the external api directly but i have no clue as to what code/language its using so i cant even look into that, but thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: this is the output
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:50:13 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 222 Content-Type: text/html Host: example.somesite.org Accept: */* Content-type: application/json X-Forwarded-For: 121.211.222.97 X-Forwarded-Host: example.somesite.org X-Forwarded-Server: example.somesite.org Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 106

Comment: Okay. Let me look into it.

Comment: try to add this line :- curl_setopt($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

Comment: that gave the exact same output except for the content length, strangely, though thank you for trying, i appreciate the help

Comment: Welcome :) We will resolve it.
write this lines and tell me output. 
$headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $headers['Content-Length'];

Comment: add this line also. curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

Comment: add both to the request or the first to the "test.php"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101997/discussion-between-ravi-hirani-and-zac-burns).